# Convert Type with ByteString to Text?

Tags: haskell

Using [conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.10), my private repo code fails to compile:

```
  Expected type: ConduitM
                   Text Void (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT IO) ()
    Actual type: ConduitM
                   ByteString
                   Void
                   (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT IO)
                   ()
```

How can I define a function?

```
type Helper a = ConduitM a Void (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT IO ()

f :: Helper ByteString -> Helper Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [`decodeUtf8C` function](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.13/conduit-combinators-1.1.1/Conduit.html#v:decodeUtf8C) together with normal fusion (the `.|` operator). If your code looks like:

```
makesText .| needsByteString
```

Then you could rewrite it as:

```
makesText .| decodeUtf8C .| needsByteString
```

You can also choose to use [`decodeUtf8LenientC`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.13/conduit-combinators-1.1.1/Conduit.html#v:decodeUtf8LenientC) if you want to ignore encoding errors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `conduit` well enough but from reading the documentation I would try something along the line of:

```hs
import Data.Void          (Void)
import Data.Text          (Text)
import Data.Text.Encoding (encodeUtf8, decodeUtf8)
import Data.ByteString    (ByteString)
import Data.Conduit

type Helper a = ConduitM a Void (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT IO) ()

f :: Helper ByteString -> Helper Text
f = mapInput encodeUtf8 (pure . decodeUtf8)
```

Using [`mapInput`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.10/docs/Data-Conduit.html#v:mapInput), [`encodeUtf8`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:encodeUtf8) and [`decodeUtf8`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:decodeUtf8)

<strike>This is untested, tell me if it works for you! :-)</strike>

Just tested quickly in ghci, it seems to work. You might want some proper error handling for `decodeUtf8` though.

Comment: shouldn't it be `mapInput decodeUtf8 (pure . encodeUtf8)` ?

Comment: That would make sense! Will edit with your suggestion and wait for feedback from OP :)

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, actually from the type of `mapInput`, it might have to be swapped. I probably shouldn't be answering stuff about conduit when I barely know it myself... :/

Comment: @basilehenry - I had the same problem, you just beat me by a minute or so ;-)